# How to run a kotlin project in android emulator

Tags: android, kotlin

How to run a Kotlin project in android emulator? my Kotlin environment is all set but I dont know to run the project in my android emulator in vs code today is my first day in kotlin i know nothing about it i just got a project from github and now i want to run that project in my android emulator

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use vs code instead of Android Studio?

Comment: @user3738870  Yes there is its a very silly reason i dont like its ui but you can answer if you know how to run in Android Studio i will try that to

Comment: It's quite simple there, as you can [create an emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) inside Android Studio, then select it when running your application.

Comment: I agree that you should get Android Studio. It has live previews of your code and includes the Android Emulator.

Comment: @ToxicFlame427 everything is ready now in Android Studio now how to run emulator is running how to run project

Answer (score 1):

You need Android Studio installed, and you also need to create at least 1 emulator via Android Studio.
Then you can install a [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DiemasMichiels.emulate#:%7E:text=To%20run%20Android%20emulators%20you,will%20always%20be%20the%20fallback.) from the Marketplace, and use it as follows:

> To run Android emulators you need to have Android studio and already
> created the Android Virtual Devices.
>
> Add the Android Studio emulator script to your settings in Visual
> Studio Code: You can either set the default path or specify a specific
> path for each operating system. The default path will always be the
> fallback.
>
> - **Default**: "emulator.emulatorPath": "~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator"
> - **Mac**: "emulator.emulatorPathMac": "~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator"
> - **Linux**: "emulator.emulatorPathLinux": "~/Android/Sdk/emulator"
> - **Windows**: "emulator.emulatorPathWindows":
>   "\Sdk\emulator"
>   or
>   "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator"
>
> Your visual studio code settings are found here:
> File -> Preferences -> Setting -> User Setting -> Extensions -> Emulator Configuration
>
> You now have the option to start Android emulators in cold boot modus.
> Activate it in your settings in Visual Studio Code:
> Android Cold Boot: true

Then to run the emulator in Visual Studio:

> Open all commands with Cmd-Shift-P and type Emulator or click the
> Emulator icon in the top right.

Comment: i turn on that  Setting now how  to run emulator and download the app in it

Comment: @Iven3636 I've added a note on how to run the emulator. Then you just need to run the app.

Comment: i did all that my emulator is also running in back but how to run that kotlin app in it? like to run a react native app we need to run npx react-native run-android to install app in the emulator so how to do that in kotlin?